# I got below error on saving product details in magento2

Tags: magento2, product

> URL key for specified store already exists.

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to import products with csv.

Comment: But i migrating from 1.7 to 2.1 in magento and database already made i only import ans use so why i get this error/

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution according to Github

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1471

Keep the URL key column blank, and make sure you have added the correct category name with upper and lower case letter.

Make sure the total length of your categories CSV column is shorter than 255 characters. You can check your url_key length too, but I haven't run into issues with my data set on that one.